# click the text ( text is linked a web url) how to open

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I am making an application using RSS feed parsing.  I've added the TextView and assigned it a URL.  How can i add redirect functionality to my TextView

xml

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/dateDetailTxt"
        android:id="@+id/descDetailTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#494949"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

java

```
    descTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
    descTxt.setLinksClickable(true);
    descTxt.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: You can also use `android:onClick="someMethod"` to handle it also and I think this is simpler also.

Comment: try this in xml first: android:clickable="true"

Comment: Why not use a button instead of TextView?

Comment: android:onClick="someMethod" not working

Comment: i using on text view

Comment: this is error in i am using in android:onClick="someMethod" 
                                                                   
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method someMethod(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'descDetailTxt'
atandroid.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)

Comment: @Si8 , thanks , android:onClick="someMethod" this method now working, thanks good and thanks you, thanks for all develeper

Comment: @Si8, hey one Error, i jest tech the text view area then show unfortunatelymy application was stoped error message, 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method someMethod(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'descDetailTxt'
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
descTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
descTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

you also have to remove autoLink="web" from your view hope this works

Comment: this is error message                                                       'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method someMethod(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'descDetailTxt''

Comment: i tried it my self and found that you dont have to do anything just use android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"  in your text view and set the text that you want. you dont have to do any of the other code. and remember your text should be in link format like http://........

Comment: this is woriking . i want to more , how to working autoLink="web" with the descTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
(working tow methods )

Comment: i cant understand what are you trying to say

Comment: I want to open browser when I click on the URL link  and when I click on the text the URL also be opened which is linked with text

Answer (score 1):

> try this

```
//add the ID to the XML and use that here for `text_view`
text_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 String url = text_view.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);

});
```

Comment: http://universitynotifications.com/b-sc-biotechnology-core-complemenatry-april-2017-practical-examination/  ,  this is my websit url , you jest open this then you see download button , you just clik this then download , i want to this method in android app , sorry my bad english

Comment: I think he is telling you the steps that need to happen to download that he wants to replicate in Android

Comment: [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kms.universitynotification ]this is my application , you just select the Calicut University Then Choose TaimTabile Section open first text then you see the download text then clike the text view then open a web